# How can I overcome a refusal by vs code to change to my selected font?

Tags: visual-studio-code, fonts

I have changed my *~/.config/Code/Usersettings.json* file to

```
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Light+",
    "workbench.editorAssociations": [],
    "python.showStartPage": false,
    "workbench.startupEditor": "newUntitledFile",
    "files.autoSave": "onFocusChange",
    "editor.fontLigatures": true,
    "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
    "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
    "python.languageServer": "Microsoft",
    "editor.fontFamily": "'Cascadia Code', monospace",
}
```

but it has no effect.

My editor appears as

[image]

I know this is the correct *settings.json* file because if I remove all references to fonts I get some horrible basic font. this is the result when I change settings to

```
    "editor.fontFamily": "'Cascadia Code'",
```

[image]

I know the font is installed because I am able to use it in other applications

This is the font in Font Manager

[image]

Comment: fonts after `monospace` have no effect, and `'monospace'` does not need `'`'s

Comment: @rioV8 Thanks but that doesn't help. I've update my question with images

Comment: it was a comment not an answer. Open the font in a font-viewer and look at the name of the font.

Comment: @rioV8 I understand it is a comment - but every little helps. I've updated the question with an image from Font Manager

Comment: you have set up VSC according to the install of the font: https://github.com/microsoft/cascadia-code/wiki/Installing-Cascadia-Code that means VSC can't find/use the font, If you use the font in an HTMl page in a browser do you see the change? If you use `Courier` or `Courier New` do you see what you changed, try to use a very strange Font

Comment: @rioV8 Thanks for the hint. Cascadia appears in an html page in Firefox, but not chrome - any ideas?

Comment: strange: I installed Cascadia (Regular), The HTML preview (WebView) could use Cascadia (looks good up till weight 500 (600+ looks weird), but the editor did not change. Google browser showed Cascadia without restart. A VSC restart enabled the use of Cascadia. Back to `Source Code Pro`

Answer (score 0):

As is often the case, the problem ran deeper than just VS Code. I followed @rioV8's advice and found that there was also a problem with Chrome, but not Firefox.

I had read somewhere that multiple versions of the font might be a problem. So I removed all files with 'cascadia' in the name and re installed the font (using pacman on Manjaro). I had then had to reboot to get VS code to recognise it, but it does and everything is working OK.